# nodejs s3-streams ReadStream throws unspecified error event

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download a file from S3 (I have successfully uploaded the file)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = AWS.S3;
const S3S = require('s3-streams');

const awsSettings = {
    ... // config stuff
}

var s3Instance = new S3(awsSettings);
module.exports = {
    download: (remoteReference, bucket, saveFile) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let download = new S3S.ReadStream(s3Instance, {
                Bucket: bucket,
                Key: remoteReference
            });
            download.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveFile))
            .on('finish', () => {
                resolve();
            })
            .on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    },
}
```

However, node crashes when calling download

crash log:

```
server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. ([object Object])
    at S3ReadStream.emit (events.js:163:17)
    at Request.httpHeaders (server/node_modules/s3-streams/lib/read.js:52:9)
    at Request.callListeners (server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at IncomingMessage.onHeaders (server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:245:24)
    at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:46:16)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:473:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:362:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

I'm not exactly sure what causes this problem but digging deep into s3-streams source, it seems that it is failing on requesting http headers and emitting an error.

Comment: Try comment out the `.on('error'...` bit.
And then the finish handler.
Still errors?

Comment: Try skipping instantiating a `new` `S3S.ReadStream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var s3Instance = new S3(awsSettings);
module.exports = {
  download: (remoteReference, bucket, saveFile) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let download = S3S.ReadStream(s3Instance, {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: remoteReference
      })
      .on('finish', () => {
        resolve();
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveFile));
    });
  },
}
```